# Batch Job to Write to VBS file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, vbscript, command-prompt

I am trying to use a batch file to write this code to a VBS file but I cannot get a successful output. Can someone help?

This is what I am trying to write to Output.vbs

```
set w = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
W.Run chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Test\Test.bat" & chr(34), 0
set w= Nothing
```

I tried this:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Test\Output.vbs" (
echo set w = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
echo W.Run chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Test\Test.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo set w= Nothing
)
```

But the data I am getting in Output.vbs is only this:

```
set w = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"
```

It obviously doesn't like these ( and ) Is there a way around this? Not super skilled in CMD other than the basics. I assume I need to escape this somehow?

Any advice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersands and nested closing parentheses, just like this:

```batch-file
@(  Echo Set w = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    Echo w.Run Chr(34^) ^& "C:\Program Files\Test\Test.bat" ^& Chr(34^), 0
    Echo Set w = Nothing) 1> "C:\Program Files\Test\Output.vbs"
```